# Tikz \fill is counteracting with geometry defined margins

Tags: tikz-pgf, memoir, geometry

I want to create my own cv-template, and I am at the very beginning of structuring the document.

I specified the paper margins with the geometry package (and will maybe change those later on).
I want to have the document divided into two columns (done by minipages), with the left column shaded in grey (done with tikz \fill).

The two columns with minipages works just fine,however, when I add the tikz \fill to the document, the text in the minipages is not any longer begining right at the top, but there seems to be a margin at the top.

How do I get rid of this margin?
I tried:

- adding `[above left,inner sep=-1, outer sep=-3]` to the tikz `\fill` anchor
- adding  `\noindent` at the beginning of the document
- defining `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` to stop paragraph indentation

Here is the minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{memoir} % Font and paper size

% LOAD PACKAGES
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor} % Required for custom colours
\usepackage{tikz} % Required for tikz drawing
\usepackage[ %top=0.5cm,right=1cm,bottom=1cm,left=1cm,
            margin=1cm, %
            showframe, %
            nohead, %
            nofoot, %
            nomarginpar %
            ]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty} % Disable all page numbering



% DEFINE COLORS
\definecolor{sidecolor}{HTML}{E7E7E7}

% DEFINE LENGTHS
\newlength{\sidecolwd} %width of side column background
\setlength{\sidecolwd}{0.3\paperwidth}
\newlength{\sidetxtwd} %width of side column text
\setlength{\sidetxtwd}{0.25\textwidth}
\newlength{\maintxtwd} %width of main column text
\setlength{\maintxtwd}{0.65\textwidth}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % Stop paragraph indentation

%BEGIN DOCUMENT
\begin{document}
    \noindent

%DRAW LEFT COLUMN
%if I comment this out, the text is aligned at the top as I want it
\begin{tikzpicture}[ remember picture, %
                        overlay, %
                        ] %

    \fill[sidecolor]
    ([above left,inner sep=-1, outer sep=-3]current page.north west)
    rectangle
    ([xshift=\sidecolwd]current page.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}



%TEXT LEFT COLUMN
\begin{minipage}[t]{\sidetxtwd}

Dies ist ein langer TExt langer text lalala
Dies ist ein langer TExt langer text lalala
Dies ist ein langer TExt langer text lalala
Dies ist ein langer TExt langer text lalala
Dies ist ein langer TExt langer text lalala
Dies ist ein langer TExt langer text lalala
Dies ist ein langer TExt langer text lalala
Dies ist ein langer TExt langer text lalala
Dies ist ein langer TExt langer text lalala
Dies ist ein langer TExt langer text lalala
\end{minipage}
\hfill
%TEXT RIGHT COLUMN
\begin{minipage}[t]{\maintxtwd}

    Dies ist ein langer TExt langer text lalala
    Dies ist ein langer TExt langer text lalala
    Dies ist ein langer TExt langer text lalala
    Dies ist ein langer TExt langer text lalala
    Dies ist ein langer TExt langer text lalala
    Dies ist ein langer TExt langer text lalala
    Dies ist ein langer TExt langer text lalala
    Dies ist ein langer TExt langer text lalala
    Dies ist ein langer TExt langer text lalala
    Dies ist ein langer TExt langer text lalala
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Which results in a margin at the top of the text. If I comment out the tikzpicture environment, there is no margin.

I am using TeXLive 2016 distribution and pdfLatex compiler.

Thank you!

EDIT 5.9.16:
picture of pdf version with tikzpicture. Margin added to the top, not as I want.
[image: pdf when added tikzpicture]

picture of pdf version without tikzpicture. No margin, as I want.
[image: pdf without tikzpicture]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! I see no margin. Have you tried to view the page at different zooms? It might be a view artifact. Can you post a screenshot of the top area of your page to show this margin that is being created?

Comment: @Alenanno Not really a margin, but an empty line. See where the text starts compared to the frame.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Ah, my bad, I misunderstood. I thought he was saying that the `\fill` was being pushed down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a paragraph break (empty line) between the `tikzpicture` and the minipage, so the minipages start on the second line. Add some `%` to fix it.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{memoir} % Font and paper size

% LOAD PACKAGES
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor} % Required for custom colours
\usepackage{tikz} % Required for tikz drawing
\usepackage[ %top=0.5cm,right=1cm,bottom=1cm,left=1cm,
            margin=1cm, %
            showframe, %
            nohead, %
            nofoot, %
            nomarginpar %
            ]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty} % Disable all page numbering



% DEFINE COLORS
\definecolor{sidecolor}{HTML}{E7E7E7}

% DEFINE LENGTHS
\newlength{\sidecolwd} %width of side column background
\setlength{\sidecolwd}{0.3\paperwidth}
\newlength{\sidetxtwd} %width of side column text
\setlength{\sidetxtwd}{0.25\textwidth}
\newlength{\maintxtwd} %width of main column text
\setlength{\maintxtwd}{0.65\textwidth}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % Stop paragraph indentation

%BEGIN DOCUMENT
\begin{document}
    \noindent

%DRAW LEFT COLUMN
%if I comment this out, the text is aligned at the top as I want it
\begin{tikzpicture}[ remember picture, %
                        overlay, %
                        ] %

    \fill[sidecolor]
    ([above left,inner sep=-1, outer sep=-3]current page.north west)
    rectangle
    ([xshift=\sidecolwd]current page.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}%
%
%
%
%TEXT LEFT COLUMN
\begin{minipage}[t]{\sidetxtwd}

Dies ist ein langer TExt langer text lalala
Dies ist ein langer TExt langer text lalala
Dies ist ein langer TExt langer text lalala
Dies ist ein langer TExt langer text lalala
Dies ist ein langer TExt langer text lalala
Dies ist ein langer TExt langer text lalala
Dies ist ein langer TExt langer text lalala
Dies ist ein langer TExt langer text lalala
Dies ist ein langer TExt langer text lalala
Dies ist ein langer TExt langer text lalala
\end{minipage}
\hfill
%TEXT RIGHT COLUMN
\begin{minipage}[t]{\maintxtwd}

    Dies ist ein langer TExt langer text lalala
    Dies ist ein langer TExt langer text lalala
    Dies ist ein langer TExt langer text lalala
    Dies ist ein langer TExt langer text lalala
    Dies ist ein langer TExt langer text lalala
    Dies ist ein langer TExt langer text lalala
    Dies ist ein langer TExt langer text lalala
    Dies ist ein langer TExt langer text lalala
    Dies ist ein langer TExt langer text lalala
    Dies ist ein langer TExt langer text lalala
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: great, thanks! 
It's always the smal things that make a mess in the end... ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can change the way you are filling that sidebar as a less complex 
solution:

```
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\AtPageLowerLeft{\color{gray!20}\rule{.3\paperwidth}{\paperheight}}}
```

---

So it would be as:
[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{memoir} % Font and paper size

% LOAD PACKAGES
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor} % Required for custom colours
\usepackage{tikz} % Required for tikz drawing
\usepackage[ %top=0.5cm,right=1cm,bottom=1cm,left=1cm,
            margin=1cm, %
            showframe, %
            nohead, %
            nofoot, %
            nomarginpar %
            ]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty} % Disable all page numbering



% DEFINE COLORS
\definecolor{sidecolor}{HTML}{E7E7E7}

% DEFINE LENGTHS
\newlength{\sidecolwd} %width of side column background
\setlength{\sidecolwd}{0.3\paperwidth}
\newlength{\sidetxtwd} %width of side column text
\setlength{\sidetxtwd}{0.25\textwidth}
\newlength{\maintxtwd} %width of main column text
\setlength{\maintxtwd}{0.65\textwidth}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % Stop paragraph indentation
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
%BEGIN DOCUMENT
\begin{document}
    \noindent

%DRAW LEFT COLUMN
%if I comment this out, the text is aligned at the top as I want it
% \begin{tikzpicture}[ remember picture, %
%                         overlay, %
%                         ] %
%     \fill[sidecolor]
%     ([above left,inner sep=-1, outer sep=-3]current page.north west)
%     rectangle
%     ([xshift=\sidecolwd]current page.south west);
% \end{tikzpicture}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\AtPageLowerLeft{%
  \color{gray!20}\rule{.3\paperwidth}{\paperheight}}}


%TEXT LEFT COLUMN
\begin{minipage}[t]{\sidetxtwd}
XDies ist ein langer TExt langer text lalala
Dies ist ein langer TExt langer text lalala
Dies ist ein langer TExt langer text lalala
Dies ist ein langer TExt langer text lalala
Dies ist ein langer TExt langer text lalala
Dies ist ein langer TExt langer text lalala
Dies ist ein langer TExt langer text lalala
Dies ist ein langer TExt langer text lalala
Dies ist ein langer TExt langer text lalala
Dies ist ein langer TExt langer text lalala
\end{minipage}
\hfill
%TEXT RIGHT COLUMN
\begin{minipage}[t]{\maintxtwd}
    Dies ist ein langer TExt langer text lalala
    Dies ist ein langer TExt langer text lalala
    Dies ist ein langer TExt langer text lalala
    Dies ist ein langer TExt langer text lalala
    Dies ist ein langer TExt langer text lalala
    Dies ist ein langer TExt langer text lalala
    Dies ist ein langer TExt langer text lalala
    Dies ist ein langer TExt langer text lalala
    Dies ist ein langer TExt langer text lalala
    Dies ist ein langer TExt langer text lalala
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```